# AngularJS re-initialise JS after statechange

Tags: javascript, dom, angularjs

I have social buttons from http://sharethis.com that I want to put on a profile page on my app. I'm using the ui-router for state management and page transitions, etc.

I've put the code I got from sharethis onto my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "66053d76-64c6-4378-8971-aac043dbbc5d", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

and the markup on my profiles page:

```
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_googleplus_hcount' displayText='Google +'></span>
```

What's happening is the social buttons are only loading when you refresh on the profile page (which is expected behaviour I guess). If the app bootstraps from say the homepage and then you transition to the profile page they aren't being loaded.

Are there any tricks that I can use to re-initialise or reload these javascript files?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

I've spend some time investigating sharethis source code and found this function which creates buttons, on page controller add this function call and this will add the buttons.

```
stButtons.makeButtons();
```

Comment: oh thanks man, I needed that for Ember and tried many of the `stLight` methods until I found this answer!

Answer (score 1):

While this might not be the best way according to documentation or best-practices, this was my solution. I had a particular view where I wanted a new set of ShareThis buttons to load. So I created a function which initialized the buttons again.

Here is the function which I placed in my controller:

```
  $scope.loadShareThis = function() {
    stButtons.makeButtons();
  }
```

I then inititalize the function using ng-init in my html:

```
<div ng-init="loadShareThis()">
   <share-buttons></sharebuttons>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer, because you want to use shareThis, but I decided to use addthis, since I did not found a way to make shareThis work with angular.

Addthis enables asynchronous loading and dynamic rendering.

You can make it work like described here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1293805-using-addthis-asynchronously.

And then you would probably want to make it into an angular directive, like described here: http://www.laurentiu-ciovica.com/2013/07/angularjs-addthis-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

Answers by AlexG and Jeff Callahan gave me the direction, but it still didn't work for me. I had to wrap

```
stButtons.makeButtons()
```

in $timeout and now it works.

In HTML I have (JADE syntax)

```
my-directive(ng-repeat="review in myReviews" ng-init="loadShareThis()")
```

and in my controller I have

```
  $scope.loadShareThis = function() {
    $timeout(function(){
      stButtons.makeButtons();
    });
  };
```

Has to do something with Angular digest cycles.